# Dealing Bash Syntax Errors

Tags: bash

I have my bash code.

```
#!/bin/bash

read message
echo $message | tr "A-Za-z" "N-ZA-Mn-za-m"
if [ $message == false ]; then
fi
done
```

It works but I get syntax errors after,

```
rot13.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
rot13.sh: line 6: `fi'
```

Now I don't expect a solution in this thread but I'm just wondering where should I go and that should I do when I get these errors? Is there any commands I can use in the compiler or documentation/checklists that check for syntax errors.

I am new to bash code so being able to check and understand there syntax error would help a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Are you expecting your second line to modify the value of `$message`? (Spoiler: it doesn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

read message
echo "$message" | tr "A-Za-z" "N-ZA-Mn-za-m"
if [ "$message" = false ]; then
    echo 'false'
fi
```

You need something between `then` and `fi`.

Before asking human help, always test your code on http://www.shellcheck.net/ before

And if you need to store the output of the `tr` command :

```
message="$(echo "$message" | tr "A-Za-z" "N-ZA-Mn-za-m")"
```

Last thing, you have a lost `done` statement at the end of the script

Comment: A lot of questions would be self replied if people know about shellcheck.

Comment: Yes, and the answers too; there is a trailing `done` in the script. :)